# replace gives different result on same string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why `replace` function gives different results on the same string? The only difference I see is whether the string is in a variable or is a literal?

I am trying this in node REPL:

```
> "2015/05/21 23:59:59".replace(/^[0-9]/g, '')
'015/05/21 23:59:59'

> var time = "2015/05/21 23:59:59"
> time.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
'20150521235959'
```

Comment: That's not the same regex.

Comment: Your regexes are not the same. The `^` is is inside the brackets in your second one.

Comment: The regular expressions are different... one is `/^[0-9]/g` and the other is `/[^0-9]/g` the difference being the position of the `^`